# Remove bottom padding between rows materialize

Tags: css, material-design, materialize

I'm having troubles with the paddings between two rows in materializecss

Padding problem

[image]

I want to remove the bottom padding. With the next code I was able to remove the left and right one:

```
<div class="col s12 m5 white no-padding">

    <div class="row center-align white"><a href="acercade.html"><img src="imagenes/IMG BOTONES-01.jpg" class="responsive-img"></a></div>
    <div class="row center-align white"><a href="transparencia.html"><img src="imagenes/IMG BOTONES-02.jpg" class="responsive-img"></a></div>

</div>
```

But it didnt affect the top or bottom one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I put a CSS class with `height: 150px !important;` and it totally works:

```
<div class="white col s12 m4 l2 no-padding">
<div class="no-padding-up-down fix-margin"><a href="acercade.html" class="fix-margin"><img src="imagenes/IMG BOTONES-01.jpg" class="responsive-img image-fit"></a></div>
<div class="no-padding-up-down fix-margin"><a href="acercade.html" class="fix-margin"><img src="imagenes/IMG BOTONES-02.jpg" class="responsive-img image-fit"></a></div>
<div class="no-padding-up-down fix-margin"><a href="acercade.html" class="fix-margin"><img src="imagenes/IMG BOTONES-03.jpg" class="responsive-img image-fit"></a></div>
```

```
.fix-margin {
height: 150px !important;
```

}

Note that I have to use it in the div class without the 'row' and in the `<a href=...>`

Answer (score 2):

Write a separate class

```
.no-padding-bottom {padding-bottom:0px !important}
```

Include that class on the div you need to remove the paddding

```
<div class="col s12 m5 white no-padding no-padding-bottom">

<div class="row center-align white"><a href="acercade.html">
  <img src="imagenes/IMG BOTONES-01.jpg" class="responsive-img"></a>
</div>
<div class="row center-align white"><a href="transparencia.html">
  <img src="imagenes/IMG BOTONES-02.jpg" class="responsive-img"></a>
</div>

</div>
```

Important tag is compulsory !

Comment: doesnt works, it didnt affect anything, I tried it before actually

Comment: Then I things it's not actually padding might be margin check it again ... If your checking in Google chrome inspect element margin will show in orange and padding will show in green ...

Answer (score 0):

```
.row {
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```